# elasticsearch highlight text between two special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I need highlight text between the two commas or full stops(.) If the length of the sentences is more than 100 and 500. I need whole highlighted text. Is there any way to get the highlighted sentence from the Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution. Just a general idea.
You can tokenize "." as PERIOD_START,PERIODD_END and "," as COMMA, than look use proxmity relevancy with descending order. So the farther away PERIOD_START is from PERIOD_END the better the score, and we reverse that.Not sure how to filter exact distance

And you can use highlighter to highlight PERIOD_START with pre_tag and post tag = `["","<b>]`, and PERIOD_END with pre_tag and post_tag = `["</br>","<b>"]`

For example,

> Hello I'm Alex END_PERIOD,START_PERIOD Joshua is a very cool dude and
>   I think He is Okay quite END_PERIOD,START_PERIOD

Will turn into

> Hello I'm Alex END_PERIOD,`(empty tag)`START_PERIOD `<b>` Joshua is a very cool dude and
>   I think He is Okay quite `</b>`END_PERIOD `(empty tag)`,START_PERIOD

proximity https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-relevance.html

highlight https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#highlight-source

Comment: Not sure if different tokens can be highlighted by different tags..so this might not be correct